# How to click recaptchaV2's Solve the challenge button using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, invisible-recaptcha

I'm trying to interact with the recaptchaV2 Solve the challenge button on image verification popup using Selenium and Python.But meet some problem.By the way,I use buster chrome extension to bypass the recaptcha.Hope can help me.Thank you~

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_extension('~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default/Extensions/mpbjkejclgfgadiemmefgebjfooflfhl/1.1.0_0.crx')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
driver.get("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/demo")
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"iframe[src^='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/anchor']")))
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "span#recaptcha-anchor"))).click()
driver.switch_to.default_content()
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"iframe[title='recaptcha challenge']")))
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button#solver-button"))).click()
```

[problem like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/im9pK.png)

Answer (score 0):

```
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
```

Is outdated use Options.

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
chrome_options = Options()
```

Also the audio button is

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#recaptcha-audio-button"))).click()
```

Not

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button#solver-button"))).click()
```

It also detects automation so use

```
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled')
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. But I want to click is no the audio button. I want to click is next to  audio button. Because I already have used Buster chrome extension to get the audio and type to word automatically.Hope you can help me. [image](https://i.imgur.com/F2CrX1W.png)

Comment: There's only audio,new challenge,help in that demo I don't see that image in that site.

Answer (score 0):

Evil company was change class name in [challenge]

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"iframe[title='recaptcha challenge expires in two minutes']")))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
driver.execute_script("Object.defineProperty(navigator, 'webdriver', {get: () => undefined})")
driver.get('https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/demo')

element_present = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@title="reCAPTCHA"]')
driver.switch_to.frame(element_present)

element_present = EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="recaptcha-anchor"]/div[1]'))
WebDriverWait(driver, 15, poll_frequency=POLL_FREQUENCY).until(element_present).click()

driver.switch_to.default_content()

time.sleep(5)

element_present = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[2]/div[4]/iframe")
driver.switch_to.frame(element_present)


try:
    buttonHolderElement = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="rc-imageselect"]/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[4]')
    actions = ActionChains(driver)
    actions.move_to_element(buttonHolderElement)
    actions.click(buttonHolderElement)
    actions.perform()
except:
    pass
```